# Use mofcomp.exe with a variable instead of a file

Tags: powershell, variables

I'm trying to export and import a WMI Class. So far all is good and I'm able to export the WMI class in the correct format:

```
Function Export-WMIDetailsHC {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        [String]$Namespace,
        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        [String]$ClassName,
        [ValidateScript({
            if (($_ -like '*.mof') -and (Test-Path -LiteralPath (Split-Path $_) -PathType Container)) {$true}
            else {throw "The path must end with the extension '.MOF' and the path location must exist."}
        })]
        [String]$Path
    )

    Process {
        Try {
            [System.Management.Textformat]$MOF = 'mof'

            if ($WmiClass = Get-WmiObject -Namespace $Namespace -ClassName $ClassName -List -EA Stop) {
                Write-Verbose "Namespace '$Namespace' ClassName '$ClassName'"
                $Result += "`n" + ('#PRAGMA NAMESPACE("\\\\.\\' + ($Namespace.Split('\') -join '\\') + '")') + "`n"
                $Result += $WMIClass.GetText($MOF)
            }
            else {
                Write-Verbose "No WMI class found with name '$ClassName' in namespace '$Namespace'"
            }

            if ($Result) {
                $Result = $Result = '#PRAGMA AUTORECOVER' + "`n" + $Result
                if ($Path) {
                    $Result | Out-File -LiteralPath $Path # Encoding is special 'UCS-2 LE BOM'
                    Get-Item $Path
                    Write-Verbose "Exported WMI details to MOF file '$Path'"
                }
                else {
                    $Result
                }
            }
        }
        Catch {
            throw "Exporting WMI details to the MOF file '$Path' for class '$ClassName' in namespace '$Namespace' failed: $_"
        }
    }
}
```

To import the generated MOF file back in the WMI reporsitory the following can be used:

```
$Path = 'C:\Temp\MyMof.mof'
$MofComp = Get-Item 'C:\Windows\System32\wbem\mofcomp.exe'
Invoke-expression "& $MofComp $Path"
```

However, I would like to know if it is possible to run `mofcomp.exe` on a variable instead of a file path? This way, there's no need to create a temp file as an in between step and the output of `Export-WMIDetailsHC` can immediately be used.

Is this possible? Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/751293/176094) I've created a poor man's version of Bash's [process substitution](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessSubstitution), which offers a way to create a transient temporary file from a command's output and return that temporary's file path.

In Bash, this temporary file gets cleaned up automatically, whereas my emulation, unfortunately, requires explicit cleanup.

Note that this is a *generic* mechanism that works with any command that (only) takes input from files - such as `mofcomp.exe` in this case.

Applied to your scenario, you would use it as follows (`cf` is an alias for  function `ConvertTo-TempFile`, defined below):

```
# Use `cf()` to save the script block's output to a temporary *.mof file
# and return that file's path.
& 'C:\Windows\System32\wbem\mofcomp.exe' (cf -Extension .mof { Export-WMIDetailsHC ... })
cf  # clean up temporary file
```

For convenience, I'm reprinting the function definition here, but more background information can be found in the [linked answer](https://serverfault.com/a/751293/176094).

```
# Define a succinct alias.
set-alias cf ConvertTo-TempFile
function ConvertTo-TempFile {
  [CmdletBinding(DefaultParameterSetName='Cleanup')]
  param(
      [Parameter(ParameterSetName='Standard', Mandatory=$true, Position=0)]
      [ScriptBlock] $ScriptBlock
    , [Parameter(ParameterSetName='Standard', Position=1)]
      [string] $LiteralPath
    , [Parameter(ParameterSetName='Standard')]
      [string] $Extension
    , [Parameter(ParameterSetName='Standard')]
      [switch] $NoBOM
  )

  $prevFilePath = Test-Path variable:__cttfFilePath
  if ($PSCmdlet.ParameterSetName -eq 'Cleanup') {
    if ($prevFilePath) { 
      Write-Verbose "Removing temp. file: $__cttfFilePath"
      Remove-Item -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue $__cttfFilePath
      Remove-Variable -Scope Script  __cttfFilePath
    } else {
      Write-Verbose "Nothing to clean up."
    }
  } else { # script block specified
    if ($Extension -and $Extension -notlike '.*') { $Extension = ".$Extension" }
    if ($LiteralPath) {
      # Since we'll be using a .NET framework classes directly, 
      # we must sync .NET's notion of the current dir. with PowerShell's.
      [Environment]::CurrentDirectory = $pwd
      if ([System.IO.Directory]::Exists($LiteralPath)) { 
        $script:__cttfFilePath = [IO.Path]::Combine($LiteralPath, [IO.Path]::GetRandomFileName() + $Extension)
        Write-Verbose "Creating file with random name in specified folder: '$__cttfFilePath'."
      } else { # presumptive path to a *file* specified
        if (-not [System.IO.Directory]::Exists((Split-Path $LiteralPath))) {
          Throw "Output folder '$(Split-Path $LiteralPath)' must exist."
        }
        $script:__cttfFilePath = $LiteralPath
        Write-Verbose "Using explicitly specified file path: '$__cttfFilePath'."
      }
    } else { # Create temp. file in the user's temporary folder.
      if (-not $prevFilePath) { 
        if ($Extension) {
          $script:__cttfFilePath = [IO.Path]::Combine([IO.Path]::GetTempPath(), [IO.Path]::GetRandomFileName() + $Extension)
        } else {
          $script:__cttfFilePath = [IO.Path]::GetTempFilename() 
        }
        Write-Verbose "Creating temp. file: $__cttfFilePath"
      } else {
        Write-Verbose "Reusing temp. file: $__cttfFilePath"      
      }
    }
    if ($NoBOM) { # UTF8 file *without* BOM
      # Note: Out-File, sadly, doesn't support creating UTF8-encoded files 
      #       *without a BOM*, so we must use the .NET framework.
      #       [IO.StreamWriter] by default writes UTF-8 files without a BOM.
      $sw = New-Object IO.StreamWriter $__cttfFilePath
      try {
          . $ScriptBlock | Out-String -Stream | % { $sw.WriteLine($_) }
      } finally { $sw.Close() }
    } else { # UTF8 file *with* BOM
      . $ScriptBlock | Out-File -Encoding utf8 $__cttfFilePath
    }
    return $__cttfFilePath
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much mklement0. This partially does what I want, except that this piece of code `[IO.Path]::GetTempFilename()` creates a file in `$ENV:Temp`. Anyhow, this is the closest I can get, so I'll mark this as solved.

Comment: @DarkLite1: My pleasure. I've amended the function to allow you to specify an output [file] path and/or filename extension. Also, to make it a better PowerShell citizen, it now creates UTF8 files _with_ a BOM by default, but you can suppress the BOM with `-NoBOM`.

Comment: P.S.: Aside from performance, the fact that a temporary file is created is not a problem per se - in fact, creating a _file_ is what allows the approach to work generically with any command that (only) accepts file input.
The unfortunate aspect is that the file must be cleaned up _manually_. With process substitution -  the `bash`, `ksh`, and `zsh` feature this approach is modeled on - cleanup is handled automatically. Cleanup here is made as easy as possible with parameterless re-invocation of `cf`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are just adding the `AUTORECOVER` pragma then you can call it like this :

`mofcomp filename.mof -Autorecover`

According to [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa392389(v=vs.85).aspx) article by MSDN :

> The MOF Compiler is available in the %Windir%\System32\wbem directory. You must specify the MOF file as the parameter of the MOF Compiler. You can also specify an Autorecover switch if you want the MOF file to be automatically recompiled if the CIM Repository ever has to be automatically recovered. For more information, type Mofcomp /? at the command prompt.

So according to that quote you must specify the file path.

For changing the namespace, can you not just call `Set-WmiInstance -NameSpace "MyNameSpace"` in powershell? I may not understand this fully but are you trying to target an instance or the abstract class?

The only option for you may be to save the file somewhere like `$env:TEMP` and then delete it once you're done.

Comment: I'm trying to avoid having a physical MOF file but use a variable instead. In your suggestion you also use a MOF file, I would like to know if this can be a variable instead of a file?

Comment: @DarkLite1 I just added another line - according to the link you must specify the MOF file as the parameter of the compiler. This seems to suggest that there is no other way, and looking at the possible switch options I don't see anything to suggest otherwise, although I may be missing something!

Comment: @DarkLite1 Another possibility may be the IMofCompiler : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa390865.aspx which looks like it has a way of programmatically compiling an MOF, although from that link I can't tell if it necessarily creates an extra file or not. Perhaps it the answer is to just create the file and delete it at the end of the script, which is messy but I can't see any other options!